# Code produces "Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable, use parentheses." when both parentheses and dimensions are in check

Tags: matlab

The code below keeps producing the error message: `"Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable, use parentheses. Otherwise, check for mismatched delimiters."`. What could be the reason? Both parentheses and indexing dimensions seem to be in check, so I'm kinda stuck with this bug.

```
m = 3;
n = 7;
x = linspace(0, pi, m);
y = linspace(0, 2*pi, n);
z = zeros(m, n);
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        z(i, j) = sin(x(i) + y(j));
    end 
end
```

Comment: I copied pasted your code. It does not give any error. Try removing what you have in your MATLAB with what you have pasted above.